# Project not Built in Active Configuration - Xamarin/Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have downloaded Xamarin.Form sample projects from github https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples

Once I open any sample projects, it does not allow me to run on iOS Simulator.

Does any one know how to handle this problem. I am using Xamarin Studio on Mac Operating System.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE-1:**

I have also found the following useful article regarding my issue http://crossplatform.io/2013/12/02/setting-the-active-configuration-in-xamarin-studio/

I chose `TabbedPageDemo.iOS--> iOS|Debug` then I could able to see iOS part, however it still does not give me an option of **Set As Start Project**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Select an iOS device or simulator from the target dropdown to enable the iOS project.

Comment: Hello Jason, please see updated figures. Dropdown is not allowed for some reasons. It does not also give me to choose Set As Startup Project option as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: Above that, where it says Debug and Default.  You may need to edit the solution configuration mapping.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
Options --> Configuration-->Configuration Mappings-->ProjectName.iOS-->Debug | iPhoneSimulator
```

Make sure to set it to **Debug | iPhoneSimulator** and NOT to **Debug | iPhone**

[image]

[image]

Now you could able to see **Set As Startup Project** option.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

In Xamarin Studio (I'm using 5.10.3), click on `Project -> Active Configuration -> Debug | iPhoneSimulator`

[image: Xamarin Studio Set Active Configuration]

Comment: Solved my problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for **Visual Studio** **Mac 2017**...

If the **Configurations Mapping** tab (as detailed in answers above) is not shown, then navigate to iOS > Options > Compiler

Set **Configuration** to `Debug`, and the **Platform** to `iPhoneSimulator`as shown here...

[image]

Then, in the **Run** toolbar, change `Debug` to `Debug|iPhone Simulator` as shown below...

[image]

To

[image]

Now you're ready to go :)

Comment: Also worked for Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to mess around with configurations - **Set As Startup Project** is the resolution.

You can see from your screenshot that you have not selected a start up project.

Comment: Simply toggling the Set as Startup project from one to another and back again fixed the problem. Editing configurations had no effect.